# How to import custom fonts in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have currently downloaded this repository:

https://github.com/adrianhajdin/portfolio_website

from this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPaLnMw2i_0&list=LL&index=3&ab_channel=JavaScriptMastery

It is a Next Js project using react that is customizable, I am however having issues with importing my own custom fonts as it does not seem to support regular CSS.

The only options that I see for changing the fonts are in these settings here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebf9V.png)

I cannot seem to import a custom font family locally using CSS. If I try to add a style.css in the same repository and reference my font family in the module export nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

which ever file you are using as `global.css` or `index.css` first import it like this in that file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

// rest of your css if have
```

then goto `tailwind.config.js and use it like this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Poppins', 'sans-serif'],
        body: ['Poppins', 'sans-serif'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: How do you do this using multiple local fonts in your repository??

Comment: Awesome man, this pretty works for me. exactly as you did it. i appreciate it.

Comment: Just a note since this tripped me up, the font import line has to be in front of any other @-rules (as was done here), per [this spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#at-import)